# Need a string to actually contain the characters \n

Tags: php

I want a string to contain '\n'

If I used these values I get the following results -

```
$a = "\n";
$b = "\\n";
$c = '\n';
$d = '\\n';
```

$a is '' {empty string}

$b is \\n

$c is \\n

$d is \\n

So is there any way to actually get \n into a string?

Comment: Do you mean literally `\n` or the newline character?

Comment: `\\n` works for me: http://viper-7.com/sH0K3s

Comment: You claim that `'\n'` results in `\\n`? That's not possible.

Comment: Well it must be possible because I am looking at it right now in the Eclipse debugger. I think it is a quirk of the debugger, the $a value of '' {empty string} is actually matching a literal \n when I use the strpos function.

Comment: Well it's not possible, eclipse debugger is wrong and you should not use it :P

Comment: Can't see how your `$c` example would ever produce the double-backslash. PHP will not add extra backslashes, and backslashes in single-quoted strings are ignored, unless it's to escape another backslash. `$c` SHOULD have worked. $a would also not be an emptys tring - if you're viewing it in an html mode, newlines are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\\n"` and `'\n'` both work → http://codepad.org/4WMGii9s

edit: even `'\\n'` works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a literal `\n`:

```
$a = "\n";
$b = "\\n";
$c = '\n';
$d = '\\n';
```

`$b`, `$c`, `$d` all work as desired.

I encourage you to read about how [single and double quoted strings work in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Particularly how characters are escaped.

#### UPDATE

If you want `\\n`, then you can use:

```
echo "\\\\n";
echo '\\\\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string to contain the slash char, and then the n char (as opposed to the single "newline" char, then $c in your question does it, and something in your output is adding the additional slash.

```
<?php
$a = '\n';
echo $a;
```

This code, when run via `>php -f myTest.php` outputs \n (the literal characters).

This is because with single-quote strings, PHP does not try to "interpret" the contents of the string for any special sequences (like the newline).